# Create a media player for Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

Hi I am creating a streaming app using Ionic Cordova and Angular Js and want to know how to create a good media (audio) player that can stream or be used offline. Is there any library that can I use? If not what is the best solution. Thank you...

Comment: Asking for recommendations for implementation is not a good for SO -- use SO to ask specific programming questions which have quantitative answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use the HTML 5 media tags for online streaming, references here: [W3 schools for media tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)